# Multiple line shown in Matsnackbar in angular

Tags: angular

For Example:

```
let msg: test;let msg2 : test3; 
For Ex: alert(msg + '\n'+ msg2);
```

First and second line
**like wise shown the matsnackbar in angular ?**

Answer (score 4):

You can use snackbar.openFromComponent method , so you can set any html as per your wish

```
snackbar.openFromComponent(NotificationComponent, {
  data:  {"firstLine" : "some data" , "secondLine" : "seocond data"}
});

import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-snack-bar',
  template: '{{ data.firstLine }} <br> {{ data.secondLine }}',  // Any Html as per your wish 
})
export class NotificationComponent{
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```